# 400 Bad Request: Cannot set property ‘status’ of undefined

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-marvel

Marvel was working until now. For some unknown reason, we get the following error message:

> Marvel: Error 400 Bad Request: Cannot set property 'status' of
>   undefined

There is nothing helpful in the Elasticsearch logs. Our cluster health is green and we have enough disk and memory space on our servers.

Comment: Did you upgrade Marvel to 2.x recently?

Comment: It used to work with 1.x and it has worked during 2 days with 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're having a problem with your template. Are you defining by any chance?

```
template="*"
```

Delete it and you should be fine.